# Discord.py unban not working. No mistakes shown discord.py 2.0.1, Python 3.10

Tags: discord.py

Tried everything I found here. No mistakes shown, unban just not working. discord.py 2.0.1, Python 3.10
Ban is working fine, but when I want to unban it's doing nothing. Nothing on console, nothing happening

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(ban_members = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def ban(ctx, member : discord.Member, *, reason = None):
    await member.ban(reason = reason)

#unban
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban(ctx, *, member):
    banned_users = await ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return'
```

Answer (score 0):

In the version of `discord.py` you're using you must not use `await` for `ctx.guild.bans()` and you must also add an `async` at `for ban_entry in banned_users:`.

You also need to remove your `'` after the return on the last line

Example:

```py
@client.command()
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def unban(ctx: commands.Context, *, member):
    banned_users = ctx.guild.bans()
    member_name, member_discriminator = member.split("#")

    async for ban_entry in banned_users:
        user = ban_entry.user

        if (user.name, user.discriminator) == (member_name, member_discriminator):
            await ctx.guild.unban(user)
            await ctx.send(f'Unbanned {user.mention}')
            return
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering. Tried what you wrote now getting this mistake: ERROR discord.ext.commands.bot Ignoring exception in command unban File "c:\Users\bot2.py", line 94, in unban member_name, member_discriminator = member.split('#') ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1) discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)